# AngularJS: What is proper way of serving async AJAX request without $http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Assume we have some service that fetch data from server. It's async and is not using AngularJS $http service.

When we deal with async stuff in Angular - we use `$q` promises. But there is one problem: promises are resolved only after `$digest`.

There are 2 possible ways to fix it:

1) `$timeout`

```
var defer = $q.defer();
$.getJSON('http://example.com/my.json')
    .success(function (data) {
       $timeout(function () {
         defer.resolve(data);
       });
    });
return defer.promise;
```

2) `$rootScope.$apply()`

```
var defer = $q.defer();
$.getJSON('http://example.com/my.json')
    .success(function (data) {
       defer.resolve(data);
    });
if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();
```

In AngularJS `$http` service second variant is used.

What the difference between both is and what is proper way to do such stuff?

You are able to try both methods in action: http://jsbin.com/otakaw/3/edit

Comment: If you can use $q, why can't you use $http ?

Comment: you should refactor your code to use $http if you can use $q

Comment: I would choose 1st solution.

Comment: Project is too big and too old. We will rewrite API module soon :) The question is about usage of AJAX requests without $http :) I suppose that lots projects have own implementation of json-rpc module or something like that and can't replace it for whole project easily :) Part of code is written without AngularJS :)

Comment: You are not even using a $timeout in example 1 ...? If 1. works, it's the better choice, as defer.resolve naturally starts a digest cycle, which is imo always preferable to manually starting it.

Comment: First variant have downside. In each test we should call `$timeout.flush()`...

Comment: Thanks, fixed first example. Added `$timeout` function.